# SQL Insert invalid column name non-numeric values only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, insert

I am writing a very basic insert statement. I noticed that the error message "Invalid column name" appears if the VALUE is a character besides a number.

The data type is VARCHAR(50) on all three columns.

Database: MS SQL 2012

Query:

```
INSERT INTO [test-db].[dbo].[Computer]
           ([id]
           ,[name]
           ,[office])
     VALUES
           (123
           ,john
           ,main)
GO
```

ERROR:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'john'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'main'.
```

Comment: include single-quotes around `varchar` values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your query to this

```
INSERT INTO [test-db].[dbo].[Computer]
       ([id]
       ,[name]
       ,[office])
 VALUES
       (123
       ,'john'
       ,'main')
GO
```

The varchar needs quotes around it to work.